# How to echo redirected stdin

Tags: linux, bash

I execute an application from a script file and redirect stdin to it from here-doc like this:

```
my_cli << HERE_DOC
enable
configure
10
exit
exit
HERE_DOC
```

This works as expected, but I don't see neither the input nor the app output. The application is an interactive prompt written in C. When I interact manually with it, I see the prompt itself and responses to my input, but when I execute the aforementioned script I see nothing. I would like it to print the input and the output as if a real user was typing. Do you know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there ought to be a better way, but you could use a wrapper function:

```
wrapper () { local text=$(</dev/stdin); echo "$text"; my_cli <<<"$text"; }
wrapper << HERE_DOC
enable
configure
10
exit
exit
HERE_DOC
```

To process the here doc line by line:

```
wrapper2 () { local line; while read -r line; do echo "$line"; my_cli <<<"$line"; done; }
```

If you manually interact with your program, does it show output? Does it output to stdout or stderr?

Another option that might work for you is [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: As far as I understand, this way I'll see the input text only. Is there a way to see it together with the output of the application. I mean, the application reacts to the input and I'd like to see the input and then the reaction for each step in the correct order.

Comment: @FireAphis: See my edit. Can you tell me what your program is or what it does? Is it a script that you can modify?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @FireAphis: It's possible that your program is interacting directly with the tty or behaves differently when it doesn't have a tty. As I mentioned in my answer, you should try `expect` which is made for this purpose and works by setting up a pseudo tty.

Answer (score 1):

I see Perl!

Well, you can't do it if you're using qx or system calls, since they are blocking in nature (yes, you can do system("program &") or call it from another thread and detach it.

Launcher thread:

```
threads->create( sub { 
                    threads->self->detach(); 
                    qx"$cmd > file1.cmd";
});
```

Main code: :

```
threads->create( sub {
while (1) { 
 get file size, if it is bigger than second ago - read new line, increase size
 parse new line, if any?
 sleep 1;
}
} );
```

Better, 
`use POE::Wheel::FollowTail`

Another solution is to redirect output of each of your programs to named fifo and read them all from your prog, keeping an eye for new lines.

```
man mkfifo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(tee /dev/fd/42 | mycmd) 42>&1 <<EOF
blah
blah
EOF
```

It won't look *exactly* like a real user - all input will be printed immediately. `expect` is probably better for this.